# bash scripts - remove duplicate rows with smaller value

Tags: text-processing, scripting

Here is an example file:

```
1 5 20 40 60
2 1 20 20 20
2 2 30 30 30
4 5 40 40 40
7 2 50 30 30
7 1 20 20 20
```

I would like to remove duplicate rows (with the same value in the first column) with a bigger value in the second column. 
I want to leave only rows with uniqe values in the first column. In this case I have duplicated rows:

```
2 1 20 20 20
2 2 30 30 30
```

and

```
7 2 50 30 30
7 1 20 20 20
```

I would like to remove rows with bigger values in the second column, in this case:

```
2 2 30 30 30
```

and

```
7 2 50 30 30
```

Hence, my goal is to select and generate the following file:

```
1 5 20 40 60
2 1 20 20 20
4 5 40 40 40
7 1 20 20 20
```

I suppose I have manage to do this in awk:

```
sort -nk2 | awk '{if(a[$1]){a[$1]=a[$1] } else {a[$1]=$0}}END{for (k in a) {print a[k]}}' | sort
```

However it works on small files. How can I replace it with something more efficient (for file with near a million of rows)?

Comment: What do you mean by smaller value? In your input, if 7 is present in the second column, are you gonna delete the duplicate row with 5 in the second column?

Comment: I am still finding little difficult to follow your example. Can you please explain a little more by editing the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `sort` itself. In the following, the first `sort` orders in ascending order of column 1 followed by column 2. This is then piped to a second `sort` which picks out one record for each distinct value in column 1. The `-s`(stable sort) flag is passed to ensure that only the first record for each value of column 1 is returned, which because of the previous sort turns out to be the record with the smallest value in column 2.

```
sort -k1,1n -k2,2n file | sort -k1,1n -s -u
```